# React Flexbox-grid build dynamically

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flexbox

i hope you can help me with this. I have been trying for quite some time now to creat a grid using flexbox-grid in react dynamically. What i want to achieve for now is to create a new row every 3 elements. I have been playing around with the meteor simple-todos example and i am trying to extend it to learn more about it.

What i have so far in terms of code is:

```
renderTasks() {
let filteredTasks = this.props.tasks;

return filteredTasks.map((task, i) => {
  const currentUserId = this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser._id;
  const showPrivateButton = task.owner === currentUserId;

  if (i % 3 == 0){
    console.log("row " + i);
    return (
      <Row>
        <Task
          key={task._id}
          task={task}
          showPrivateButton={showPrivateButton}
        />
      </Row>
    );
  }else{
    console.log("col " +i );
    return (

      <Task
        key={task._id}
        task={task}
        showPrivateButton={showPrivateButton}
      />
    );
  }

});
}
```

The problem here is that i cant leave the row open and have to close it immediatly. I assume this should not be to hard to achieve but i googled quite a bit and could not find anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do. First, I would group the tasks according to the row where they should be placed. Then I would have an array of arrays, more or less like this:

```
[
  [ task_1, task_2, task_3 ],
  [ task_4, task_5 ]
]
```

Then I would map over this array to render each row. Finally, to render a row, I would map over that row's tasks and render each task.

Something like this:

```
renderTasks() {
  let filteredTasks = this.props.tasks;
  let taskRows = filteredTasks.reduce(function (rows, task, i) {
    let rowIndex = Math.floor(i / 3);

    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      rows[rowIndex] = [task]
    } else {
      rows[rowIndex].push(task)
    }
    return rows;
  }, []);

  return taskRows.map(this.renderTasksRow);
}

renderTasksRow(rowTasks) {
  return <Row>{rowTasks.map(this.renderTask)}</Row>;
}

renderTask(task) {
  const currentUserId = this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser._id;
  const showPrivateButton = task.owner === currentUserId;

  return (
    <Task
      key={task._id}
      task={task}
      showPrivateButton={showPrivateButton}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot! Now that i think about it this is actually pretty logical to split it into different functions. I was so bent on trying to get everything done in one that i tripped over this. Thanks a bunch for the great help :)

Comment: In React, every time I map over an array to render a group of elements, I almost always extract that function. Not only does that make my code more focused but it also makes it more readable because it requires less indentation.